# Loop after page content

Tags: loop, pages, query, the-content

I just upgraded to 3.4.2 from 2.9 (i know, i know, but if it ain't broke...) I have page templates that are (or at least were) set up to display the page content first, then start a loop of posts, like so:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-title">ABOUT THE SITE</div>
    <div id="content-main">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/headline.gif" />
        <div class="nopad"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-title" style="color: #05B2A9;">POSTS BY DATE</div>
        <div id="comments">
            <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args= array(
                    'cat' => 8,
                    'paged' => $paged
                );
                query_posts($args);
            ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                $key="main img";
                $my_main_img = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
                $key="thumb img";
                $my_thumb_img = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
            ?>
            <div <?php post_class() ?>>
                <div class="blog-list">
                    <div class="blog-list-img">
                         <!-- do stuff -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : endif; ?>
            <div id="blog-list-more">
                <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('&nbsp;') ?></div>
                <div class="previous"><?php next_posts_link('&nbsp;') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This worked great in 2.9 but in this new upgrade it isn't displaying the page content. I have multiple page templates and was able to fix it on the pages that ran simple queries (like list of the blog contributors) by putting

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

before `<div id="content">`, but as you can imagine on the main blog archive page this isn't an option. (I tried just to be sure).

So how does one get the contents of the page outside the main loop? Do I have to run two loops? It seems this would be a simple enough thing but I can't work out how. I can't run a simple query in this page because there's all sorts of crazy stuff going on in there. Or can I?

Answer (score 2):

Updating a theme isn't that hard. But it's necessary to let it play nice with the current version of the core.

Here're some notes on what you might need to do:

- Query
- Templates
- Post Thumbnails & featured images

### The query

[Nowadays, we're using `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385) for such cases, where you need to do another (manual) query aside from WordPress' default query.

So you'd call:

```
$wpse69629_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'   => 8
   ,'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
) );
if ( $wpse69629_query->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $wpse69629_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $wpse69629_query->the_post();

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

### Template Hierarchy

As you have a query that does nothing than loading posts from a specific category, you might consider adding another template that triggers only for this category. This will save you an additional query.

Just copy your code (without the query, but with a default loop) into a new file named `category-8.php`.

[image]

### The post thumbnail

[With (afaik) WP 2.9, post thumbnails/feat.images arrived.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) It just seems that this wasn't implemented in your theme back then.

You can now grab the assigned thumbnail (featured image meta box) simply by calling [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) in list views and `()` for single views.

The support for this feat. and the size will be set inside your functions php with something like that:

```
function wpse69629_feat_img_size()
{
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

    set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse69629_feat_img_size' );
```

You can then call it like this in the template:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. I suppose I should expand on my post, though. I *have* written and maintained current themes so am [fairly] familiar with new features. I'm a designer tho, not a developer, so some of this comes easier than others (and yes, I need to get those thumbnails changed cause that script is heavy on my server). The page is currently set up as a custom template, so the slug matches the category name - in this case http://www.plasmodium.net/podcasts. so are you saying I use the loop for `the_content()` and query for the category list?

Comment: but the page content is managed in the actual pages. not a post. so if i do that how do i link the page content to the category page? sorry if i'm missing something. My pages: About, Contact, Podcast are about.php, contact.php and podcast.php with page templates for that content, but they also display queried data... or are you saying that i should have podcast.php and category-8.php as two documents, with `the_content()` in podcast.php and the loop structure in category-8.php? i'm feeling very dumb right now. thanks so much for helping

Comment: but there isn't one master style for them. all the categories have different styles associated with them and will display different sidebars. can you still use one master category page for this and still have variable styles/content and pretty permalinks to display the slug?

Comment: Please read into the Codex on Templates and Hierarchy. The comments are to clarify - not to teach basics. Thanks. And please clean up your comments.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I never expected a lesson from you, I was just asking for clarification because you're answer didn't make sense. It just sounded backwards. Everyone has a different thought process. Mine is visual. I will enlist a friend for help. Most of the codex may as well be written in Klingon.

Comment: @KristinaChilds [Please read about the Template File Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_File_Hierarchy). You'll see that there are special files that WP core loads automatically for e.g. "categories". You can add a basic file that serves for all categories and then special files that override this hierarchy for e.g. "category-8". So if `podcast.php` is your wrapper for `category-8.php`, then simply rename that file and drop the additional query on top.

Comment: After doing some more work on this I still don't think the end result is understood. I already use category-slug.php to display things, like a query for a genre within the `podcast` category. However I am specifically referring to a PAGE. Not a post. The PAGE in this theme pulls up the static content describing what the podcast is all about, just like the "About" or "Contact" page displays static content. Only in 2.9 I was also able to run a query to show the most recent 10 or so episodes as well. So yes, you are right, but that's not the end goal here. In this case, the query is secondary.